# Removing a first space in input while focusing with space bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

When press spacebar it calls a function and that function focus a input tag and it already creates a space in that input and I don't want it. How do I remove that space ?

Here is what I have done..

```
<input type="text" class="user-answer" name="useranwer">
```

```
var userAnwer = document.querySelector('.user-answer');

window.addEventListener('keypress', myFun);

function myFun(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    userAnwer.focus();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). You also have to check the value to allow space afterwords.

```js
var userAnswer = document.querySelector('.user-answer');
window.addEventListener('keypress', myFun);

function myFun(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 32 && (e.target.value == undefined || e.target.value == "")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    userAnswer.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="user-answer" name="useranswer">
```

Comment: @jo_va, which browser? I am getting it right in chrome:)

Comment: I am testing in chrome: `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Comment: You are not focusing the input field either

Comment: @jo_va, isn't it meaningless as the element is already focused?

Comment: no it isn't as the OP wants to focus the field when the spacebar is pressed anywhere in the page

Answer (score 1):

You could prevent the default from happening which would be adding the space in this example.

```
function myFun(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 32 && userAnwer.value.length == 0) {

        e.preventDefault();

        userAnwer.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: If this helps, please accept it as the correct answer! Thank you :)

Comment: There must be something about *first space* mentioned in the question. Space not allowed in between words:)

Comment: Ah, I see! This would only work if there is no other spaces! Of course, you're right @Mamun

Comment: @Mamun I've updated it to work with multiple words.